# Set condition in XML table property (SAP UI5)

Tags: javascript, xml, syntax-error, sapui5, conditional-statements

I'd like to set a condition in my xml template when setting the "rowSettings" aggregation of my  `sap.ui.table` .

Here's how I tried it so far (based on other questions I found):

```
<table:Table id="changedData">
    <table:columns>
        <!-- Columns created in controller -->
    </table:columns>
    <table:rows>
        <!-- Rows created in controller -->
    </table:rows>
    <table:rowSettingsTemplate >
        <table:RowSettings highlight = "{= ${changedModel>highlight} == 'yellow' ? 'Warning' : ${changedModel} == 'green' ? 'Success' : 'None'}"/>
    </table:rowSettingsTemplate>
</table:Table>
```

That's how the data for my "changedModel" looks like:
[image]

So the "highlight" property is supposed to inform about the needed highlighting.

When using the code as above, I get a Syntax error, even though I checked my syntax 100 times. 
That's the error:

> Expected '}' and instead saw '=' in expression binding {= ${changedModel>highlight} == 'yellow' ? 'Warning' : ${changedModel} == 'green' ? 'Success' : 'None'} at position 29.

What's wrong with my code?

**Sample Output**
changedData

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
COL01: "00000000"
COL02: "Sonja"
COL03: "Deißenböck"
COL04: "Studentin"
COL05: "33403215"
COL06: "Hochschule München"
COL07: "Teststraße 2"
COL08: "20160115"
COL09: " 120.00 € "
highlight: "yellow"
__proto__: Object
1:
COL01: "00000001"
COL02: "Leon"
COL03: "Maschine"
COL04: "Student"
COL05: "57945612"
COL06: "TUM"
COL07: "Teststraße 3"
COL08: "20160116"
COL09: " 160.00 € "
highlight: "yellow"
__proto__: Object
2:
COL01: "00000002"
COL02: "Sabine"
COL03: "Betrieb"
COL04: "Studentin"
COL05: "45613789"
COL06: "LMU"
COL07: "Teststraße 4"
COL08: "20160117"
COL09: " 200.00 € "
highlight: "yellow"
__proto__: Object
```

changedModel

```
{columns: Array(10), rows: Array(7)}
columns: Array(10)
0: {columnId: "COL01"}
1: {columnId: "COL02"}
2: {columnId: "COL03"}
3: {columnId: "COL04"}
4: {columnId: "COL05"}
5: {columnId: "COL06"}
6: {columnId: "COL07"}
7: {columnId: "COL08"}
8: {columnId: "COL09"}
9: {columnId: "highlight"}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
rows: Array(7)
0: {COL01: "00000000", COL02: "Sonja", COL03: "Deißenböck", COL04: "Studentin", COL05: "33403215", …}
1: {COL01: "00000001", COL02: "Leon", COL03: "Maschine", COL04: "Student", COL05: "57945612", …}
2: {COL01: "00000002", COL02: "Sabine", COL03: "Betrieb", COL04: "Studentin", COL05: "45613789", …}
```

Comment: Have you set the compatVersion on your index.html file to edge?

data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"

Comment: ooh I never read about that! Thanks! Now I'm working in a "child" project and I'm only inheriting the index.html file from the parent, which I don't want to touch.. Is there a way of adding it anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you set the compatVersion to edge or your binding syntax to complex, otherwise you will not be able to use complex binding.

```
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

Regarding your binding, you're missing a ">highlight" on your second condition.

```
<table:RowSettings highlight = "{= ${changedModel>highlight} === 'yellow' ? 'Warning' : ${changedModel>highlight} === 'green' ? 'Success' : 'None'}"/>
```

Comment: I added the compatVersion and complex binding to my XML view by defining a script tag. Therefore I added this xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" and then my script tag like this:
<html:script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
 src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
 data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
 data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"/>
 But I still get the same syntax error..

Comment: I totally missed it, you're using "==" instead of "===". Please rectify and let me know if the error persists.

Comment: you're right, that definetly solved my error message! but it doesn'T get applied for some reason.. how do correctly define the CompatVersion if I can'T access the index.html file?

Comment: oh hold on, I just checked the parent project's index.html version and the two settings are actually defined.. so it should work.. :O

Comment: Is it not working or just applying highlight = None ? Trying changing the default of your conditional statement to something other than None to see if the binding is getting processed. If it is, the problem is on your model's data. If it isnt than the expression binding isnt getting parsed.

Comment: It's not working, highlight doesn'T get applied at all.. so the expression binding isn't parsed, but I don't know how to debug or how to find the problem..
I tried simply <table:RowSettings highlight = "{= ${changedModel>highlight} === 'yellow' ? 'Warning'> but that didn't work

Comment: it's still not working.. I would love to hear back from you!

Comment: My apologies, I just attempted this locally and it worked. Without access to your code my help is limited. The databinding expression is working so I would say either define your RowSettings on the controller where you also add your columns and rows or you can try to define a formatter to parse the highlight value.

Comment: Totally understand this!
Would you be so kind and show me how I would add the RowSettings in my JS Controller?

Comment: Something like this:
var rowSettingsTemplate = new sap.ui.table.RowSettings({
    highlight: "{= ${Status} === 'yellow' ? 'Warning' : ${Status} === 'green' ? 'Success' : 'None'}"
   });
   var table = this.byId("table").setRowSettingsTemplate(rowSettingsTemplate);

Comment: Hmm no unfortunately not, but I'll look further into it, thanks anyway!

Comment: I feel like the "changedModel>highlight" part is not correct, since highlight is only a column name...

Comment: I attempted to set a RowSettings in a JS Controller and the code I placed in the comment above works well. Keep in mind that I named my property status and has no prefix (e.g changedModel>) since my model does not have a name. I take it your model has a name (changedModel) so yes, you need the model name prefix on your bindings.

Comment: Hmm ok, so if I have this
${changedModel>highlight}
and my Model gets defined like that:
changedModel.setData({ 
 columns: oColumns, 
 rows: changedData, 
}); 
where "highlight" is the last entry for "columns", it doesn't work.. I feel like I'm accessing it wrong?

Comment: Any chance you could create a JSBin with your example? Would make it super easy to understand and fix.

Comment: I don't know if I did it right: https://jsbin.com/mejexusaqo/edit?html,js,output
that's some sample data in the table and the exact code how I fill the table dynamically. Let me know if you need more!

Comment: Plus, I'll ad an output of "changedData" and "changedModel" to my question!

Comment: The problem is in your binding, when you called setModel you did not give it a name so your highlight binding should be {highlight} and not {changedModel>highlight}. So your row setting would be like this:
"{= ${highlight} === 'yellow' ? 'Warning' : ${highlight} === 'green' ? 'Success' : 'None'}"